# Graph Algorithm to Blood Pressure systolic and Diastolic

Tags: arduino

For measuring Blood-Pressure Systolic and Diastolic values, One must proceed in 3 steps,
Inflation -  Increment of pressure around the Wrist/Arm until the blood flow from limb to Heart is completely stopped usually around 180mmHg tops.

Controlled Deflation - This is pretty self explanatory, When the external Pressure slowly decreases, the pressure sensor int the Air volume, gets Pulsating changes in Air pressure, of Increasing amplitudes (Locally Speaking) , using this Plot of ***Pulses throughout the Deflation Range***, we can **estimate** the Systolic and Diastolic points fairly accurately

Comment: Can be done optically, although appears not very reliable: http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/how-accurate-are-wristband-heart-rate-monitors/

Comment: Optical measurement with IR + Red LEDs can determine HR and SpO2 at a fingertip or an earlobe. Not blood pressure. And the wrist is not an ideal place for measurement, there's too much other anatomical stuff in the way. And a watch wristband introduces a lot of unwanted motion artifacts that are larger than the signal. As far as I know, nobody's figured out how to do this well in a wristwatch form factor.

Comment: @pjc50, heart rate and blood pressure are not the same things

Comment: I have not heard of any way of measuring blood pressure without having to physically squeeze the artery, the most accurate being the brachial artery.  In a hospital in patient setting blood pressure can be measured intra-arterially, putting a temporary probe inside the artery.  This would be of no use to your situation - I just mention it as the only way of measuring blood pressure that I know of that doesn't require a physical squeezing of the artery.

Answer (score 2):

First, it may help to understand how blood pressure is measured:

When a cuff is placed on your arm, it is inflated until the doctor or logic in a machine can no longer hear the blood pulsing on the restricted side of your arm. They then watch the gauges and listen as they lower the pressure in the cuff until they hear a more muffled, whooshing heart rate on the restricted side of your arm. Looking at the gauge when this happens shows the pressure in the cuff and and the pressure in your arteries when they are equal. This is the systolic measurement, the larger number.

They then continue to let air out of the cuff until it sounds like blood is circulating unrestricted, and this is the diastolic measurement, the smaller number.

Can this be done with a smart watch? Sure. Can it be done with math? Sure. Can it be done with a smart watch that doesn't exert large amounts of pressure on your wrist? Probably not. There are too many variables from person to person to account for something that is already incredibly variable, like blood pressure, or serum cholesterol levels.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not a big deal, but technically the diastolic blood pressure is recorded just as the sounds disappear as you are letting the air out of the cuff.

Comment: TIL. I aint a pro, I've just watched and felt it enough to fill in the blanks